# How to connect React SPA with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, single-page-application

Folks I would like to ask for a resolution for this use case if it's possible or not.

**Use Case**
The functionality currently is that both React and Node code are in the same repo. Where we build the React and the build is placed in /public/ directory. NodeJS loads the static files from the /public/ directory and serve the SPA.

The required functionality is that:
React SPA build will live on server **A**
NodeJS build will live on server **B**

How can I serve the static files located in Server A from Server B?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your server code (assuming you are using expressJS).
Also I would call name react project `client/` instead of `serverB`.

```
// file:<project-root-dir>/server/main.js
const STATIC_FILES = path.join(__dirname, '../client/', 'build') // feel free to change `client` to `serverB`

//..
const app =  express()

//....

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(STATIC_FILES))
  app.get('/*', (_, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(STATIC_FILES, 'index.html')))
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do like this
`const STATIC_FILES = <client_remote_url>/public`

Comment: 'remote url' ??? where are you keeping your react build ?

Comment: my workflow in production is, running react build command thats it, by backend will automatically serves react app (as shown in above snippet),  no need of live-server or anything like that to serve react.